# How can I query for float/int value or string in a django model using Q Objects?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.8, django-q

**Django version=1.8 , IDE=pycharm, python 2.7**

I have a search form and I want to search and list items("products") in model based on string matching product title or product description or product price.

Below is my "searchitems" part inside views.py . Also im confused what does the line below do in get_queryset function. Cheers

```
   qs = super(ProductListView, self).get_queryset(*args,**kwargs)
```

#

```
# Search inside model function
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = super(ProductListView, self).get_queryset(*args,**kwargs)
    query = self.request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        qs = self.model.objects.filter(

            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(description__icontains=query) |
            Q(price=query)
        )
    return qs

class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    queryset=Product.objects.all()  #no need to define this as it is a default
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context
```

Below is models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    from django.db.models.signals import post_save
    from django.utils.text import slugify

    # Create your models here.

    class ProductQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
        def active(self):
            return self.filter(active=True)


    class ProductManager(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return ProductQuerySet(self.model, using=self.db)

        def all(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.get_queryset().active()


    class Product(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        objects = ProductManager()

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("product_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
            # OR use this- return "/product/%s"%(self.pk)


    class Variation(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product)  ##this means each Variation is related to single product
        title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
        sale_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, null=True, blank=True)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        inventory = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  # default=-1 means unlimited

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title

        def get_price(self):
            if self.sale_price is not None:
                return self.sale_price
            else:
                return self.price

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return self.product.get_absolute_url()


    # for post save receiver


    def product_saved_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
        # sender=modelclass, instance=actual instance being saved,created=boolean true if record was created
        product = instance
        variations = product.variation_set.all()
        if variations.count() == 0:
            new_var = Variation()
            new_var.product = product
            new_var.title = "Default"
            new_var.price = product.price
            new_var.save()

    post_save.connect(product_saved_receiver, sender=Product)


    # product image
    # you need to install python pillow library to support.


    # it checks if file uploaded is actually an image and checks extension
    # class ProductImage(models.Model):
    #     product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    #     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/') #image will be uploaded to media/mediaroot/products
    #
    #     def __unicode__(self):
    #         return self.product.title

    #slugify
    def image_upload_to(instance, filename):
        title = instance.product.title
        slug = slugify(title)
        file_extension = filename.split(".")[1]
        # or  basename,file_extension = filename.split(".")
        new_filename = "%s.%s" %(instance.id,file_extension)
        return "products/%s/%s" %(slug, filename)

    # above function changed for slugfying

    class ProductImage(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to) #image will be uploaded to media/mediaroot/products

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.product.title
```

With above codes i can search and list according to price eg. 50 or 67.89 but cannot search for strings and get below error

http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/?q=eric clapton riding with the king

```
ValidationError at /products/

[u"'eric clapton riding with the king' value must be a decimal number."]

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/?q=eric%20clapton%20riding%20with%20the%20king
Django Version:     1.8.4
Exception Type:     ValidationError
Exception Value:    

[u"'eric clapton riding with the king' value must be a decimal number."]

Exception Location:     C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py in to_python, line 1602
Python Executable:  C:\Anaconda\python.exe
Python Version:     2.7.10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the price requires a decimal value we should supply it a decimal value. Try the following view:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = super(ProductListView, self).get_queryset(*args,**kwargs)
    query = self.request.GET.get("q", False)  # provide default value or you get a KeyError
    if query:
        filter_arg = Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(description__icontains=query)
        try:
            filter_arg |= Q(price=float(query))
        except ValueError:
            pass
        qs = self.model.objects.filter(filter_arg)
    return qs
```

`qs = super(ProductListView, self).get_queryset(*args,**kwargs)` This is used to obtain the queryset provided by the parent classes of our view class `ProductListView`. Look in to python classes and inheritance here:
http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/

`filter_arg |= Q(price=float(query))` this is used to append to our filter_arg value. It's the same as `filter_arg = filter_arg | Q(price=float(query)`

`float(query)` with this we are trying to convert the query variable to a float and we put this in a `try` statement because it could give us a `ValueError` in which case the `query` value is not a `float`.

Comment: thanks @Bogdan that worked right away. im confused what qs = super(ProductListView, self).get_queryset(*args,**kwargs) and filter_arg |= Q(price=float(query)) did here.. can you provide some more information or links . Gracias :)